# String value of token in yacc and lex

Tags: compiler-construction, flex-lexer, yacc, lex

I am starting to learn lex and yacc to parse a a shell's input. For now I am just trying to  write the parser for something like this command | command | command. I am failing miserably to try to capture the string value for command, printing it gives me a segmentation fault. Here is the code for it:

lex file:

```
    %{

#include <stdio.h>
#include "y.tab.h"
#include <string.h>
%}

%%

grep|vim|ls|who     {yylval = strdup(yytext); return COMMAND;}
"|"                 return PIPE;

%%
```

yacc file:

```
%{

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define YYSTYPE char*
void yyerror(const char* str)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "error: %s\n", str);
}

int yywrap()
{
    return 1;
}

main()
{
    yyparse();
}


%}

%token PIPE COMMAND

%%


statement:
        command
        |
        statement PIPE command
        ;


command:
        COMMAND
        {
            printf("command: %s encountered\n", $1);
        }
        ;
```

I believe that for some reason the $1 in the command block is null which means that strdup also returns null. I would appreciate it if someone could tell me what I am missing, Thanks!

Comment: *Why* do you believe `$1` is NULL? Did you print it out with a `%p` format?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `#define YYSTYPE` in your yacc/bison grammar file, you must also put exactly the same `#define` in your flex scanner file, and it must come before the bison/yacc header is included. Otherwise, `yylval` will have the wrong type in the scanner, and assigning to it will be Undefined Behaviour.

That should produce a compiler warning. Please ensure you always compile with warnings enabled.